# fetch image and text from database using joomla 2.5

Tags: module, joomla2.5

i have one one issue in fetch image and text from database by module what to do for this issue and i add my table name and field name `#__home_service_item` this is my table name in that table two field one is image and image_name than i have one error for that question i display my error

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\Joomla_2.5.8-Stable-Full_Package\modules\mod_home\tmpl\default.php on line 40
```

please give me any clue for that problem i also add my code

```
 <?php
    defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

    $items = $params->get('items', 1);
    $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = "SELECT id
                         FROM #__home_service_item
                        WHERE published = '1'
                        ORDER BY id DESC";
    $db->setQuery( $query, 0 , $items );
    $rows = $db->loadObjectList();
    foreach($rows as $row)
    {
          echo 'ID: <A href="'. JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_home_service&id='.$row->id.'&task=view') .'">'.$row->id.'</A> </br>';
    }
    ?>
```

please give one clue

Comment: On a side note, remove the `&` symbol before `JFactory`, use lowercase for your `<a>` tags, and I would advise using Joomla 2.5 coding standards for you [Database Query](http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase/2.5)

Comment: do print_r($rows) and see if any records are returning from the database.

Answer (score -1):

do print_r($rows) and see if any records are returning from the database. I think that you have a problem with your query. If there are no results returning try enclosing your foreach statement with in a try catch or ignore warnings.

Also try to set $db->setQuery($query); instead of $db->setQuery( $query, 0 , $items );

If you just need one row result use $db->loadResult();